# Eject Virtual Devices permanently

Tags: finder, install, external-disk, disk-volume

I installed some programs (e.g. `Sequel Pro`), when I eject the virtual device from the Finder it seems ok but after some time it is re-added.

- Is there a way to remove them permanently?
- What is the reason of this behaviour?

**Edit:** 
My machine is a MBP 15" 2016 with macOS Sierra 10.12.6.

The problem does't give any error. Simply if I remove the devices they reappear after a while. The devices now are `Sequel Pro 1.1.2` and `fastnosql-1.5.1`. I don't know if this is OS related or single programs related.

[image]

Comment: I think this question would be best addressed to the makers of Sequel Pro.

Comment: @Tetsujin, SequelPro is not the only program with this behaviour...

Comment: Then you need to be far more specific. What 'virtual device', what error if any, machine, OS... there's nothing to go on here.

Comment: I would start by ejecting the .dmg files via Finder or Disk Utility and then either move them to a different location or delete them. Then wait and see what happens next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple general explanation for why this happens: macOS will make shortcuts (aliases / sym links) to files that exist on a mounted disk Image or remote volume.

When you open that shortcut, the images get re-mounted assuming there are no password is needed or the credentials are cached in an unlocked keychain.

Now - you might need to do some work sleuthing why you are running files from those specific images, but the general idea is you can look around and worst case copy the DMG files to an external drive and delete them locally to see what things complain about a missing link / missing file when they run or open.

The most common case is you didn’t copy apps from the DMG to /Applications or a local folder and apps in the dock or elsewhere point at the DMG and not a local copy.

Comment: This worked. I was running the Applications on my dock that were linked to the images instead of the ones in the `Applications` folder.
I am just wondering where they mount the .dmg from if I deleted that.

Comment: @Andrea Bergonzo, Remove the apps from the Dock, add the apps from the DMG to the Applications folder, then put them in the Dock from the Applications folder of just run them from Applications and set the option to Keep in Dock from the Dock Tile's context menu. Then get rid of the DMG files if you don't have a need to keep them.

Comment: @user3439894, this was what I did, except for the fact that the .dmg files are no more in the Download folder so I was wondering where they were remounted from.